# PHP Round a decimalnumber with specific interval

Tags: php, rounding

I have a number that I want to look up in my database. The database intervals are like this:

```
0,78
0,82
0,86
0,90
0,94
0,98
1,02
1,06
1,10
1,14
```

So the number is added with 0.04 all the time.

The numbers I want to look up is like this:

```
0,77778
0.91666 
1,14286
1,50000
1,76923
```

How can I round it to the nearest 0.04 ?

So they would look like this:

```
0,78
0.90 
1,14
1,50
1,78
```

Comment: Can you read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What is the purpose of your rounding attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make it to the nearest multiple of 0.04 here is a function that does the job:

```
function round_to_0_04($round)
{
    $int_val = round($round * 100);
    $rest = $int_val % 4;
    $rounded_val = $int_val - $rest;
    return $rounded_val /100;
}
```

If the number needs to be uneven (starting from 0.02 instead of 0), you should use it as follows:

```
$number = ...;
round_to_0_04($number - 0.02) + 0.02;
```

Or just modify the function as follows:

```
function round_to_0_04_uneven($round)
{
    $round -= 0.02;
    $int_val = round($round * 100);
    $rest = $int_val % 4;
    $rounded_val = $int_val - $rest;
    return $rounded_val /100 + 0.02;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that it should start with 0 and then 0.02 and then 0.06 and then 0.10. How can I twist the code so it starts "uneven" ? Testet your code, and it works perfectly ! I just need to start "uneven", so 0.91666666666667 is going to be 0.90, instead of 0.92. With the code above, the result is 0.92. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Any ideas how to make it start 0.02 ? :D

Answer (score 1):

Use round and a bit of math.

```
round(($number-0.02)/0.04)*0.04+0.02
```

or this if 0.02 shift is mistake

```
round($number/0.04)*0.04
```

Comment: He want to round to the next 0.04, not by 2 digits: `0.91666 -> 0.9` and not `0.92`

Comment: The nearest multiple of 0.04 is not 0.9, but 0.92, since 0.9/0.04 is not an integer (it is 22.5)